# tikz figures in a grid (rows and columns) with common legend

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have 9 pgfplots plots(or tikz figures) and I want to put them in a grid of 3x3 i.e. 3 rows and 3 columns. So each of the 3 rows, contain 3 figures side by side horizontally. How to achieve this ?

Secondly, all these plots have same legend entries. I don't want to put them inside the figure. I know, how to place them outside but 9 outside legend entries will consume a lot of page space which is completely unnecessary as all of them are same. I just want a single legend entry for all plots. It may be placed at any convenient position (but I prefer top or bottom, for more clarity).

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: @Bobyandbob:Thanks. Ok. I got first part using subcaption package. But the second part still remains unsolved.  I tried adding legend only to figure at position 3 row and 2 column (at bottom to that particular figure). However the figure readjusted itself to fit the legend also. I want a uniform grid and only one legend.